# The trouble with Charting with Google Earth Engine

Tags: charts, time-series, timestamp, google-earth-engine

In Google Earth Engine, I want to get the NDVI index from several images of the Sentinel 2 satellite with different dates, then I will estimate other parameters from this index. To do this, I need to convert the resulting NDVI images to an image collection. But to chart it, it gives the following error:

Error generating chart: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start".

It seems that when converting to a collection image, the temporal information of the images is lost. with this condition, how can I fix it?

Link to the code:  https://code.earthengine.google.com/47cd9e7f65b143242ebb238d136bf760

Code:

```
var sentinel1 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20181214T072311_20181214T072733_T39SVV');
var sentinel2 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20181219T072319_20181219T072610_T39SVV');
var sentinel3 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20181224T072311_20181224T072313_T39SVV');

var ndvi1 = sentinel1.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);
var ndvi2 = sentinel2.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);
var ndvi3 = sentinel3.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);

var NDVI_COL = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([ndvi1, ndvi2, ndvi3]);

var chart = ui.Chart.image.series(
NDVI_COL, geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(),10,'system:time_start');
print(chart);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/45a31f4318af1e7062304d2f8c17c753)

Make a collection of selected images, then plot

```
var sentinel1 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20181214T072311_20181214T072733_T39SVV');
var sentinel2 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20181219T072319_20181219T072610_T39SVV');
var sentinel3 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20181224T072311_20181224T072313_T39SVV');

var S2 = ee.ImageCollection([sentinel1, sentinel2, sentinel3])
                .filterBounds(geometry)
                .map(function(image){return image.clip(geometry)});
                
print('collection of Selected Images to plot: ', S2);

var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

var S2_NDVI = S2.map(addNDVI);

var NDVI_S2 = ee.ImageCollection(S2_NDVI.select(["NDVI"], ["NDVI"]));

var chart =
    ui.Chart.image
        .seriesByRegion({
          imageCollection: NDVI_S2,
          band: 'NDVI',
          regions: geometry,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 10,
          xProperty: 'system:time_start'
        })
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Average NDVI Value by Date',
          hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
          vAxis: {
            title: 'NDVI',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
        });
        
print(chart);
```

Comment: Did it worked as per your requirements? @AmirMohamadAbasi

Comment: Thank you for your code. but I need images with different dates, so I can't use image collection first. I want code that can make image collection from images and then chart the results.

Comment: Can’t understand the question properly. Do you mean that the dates are random/not continuous, by which you want to make image collection ?

Comment: yes, some random images that I want to make an image collection from them and then chart the NDVI

Comment: I have changed the code, hope it works, you can add/delete/update the number of images of your choice in the image collection. @AmirMohamadAbasi

Comment: @AmirMohamadAbasi Well, You may accept the answer if it fulfilled your requirement, thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: for sure I will